# Convert string formatted as list to actual list

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
mylist = "[{'answer': Markup(u'7'), 'question': u'5 and 2'}, {'answer': u'8', 'question': u'2 and 6'}]"
```

I would like to convert it to an actual list. So it would be like:

```
mylist = [{'answer': Markup(u'7'), 'question': u'5 and 2'}, {'answer': u'8', 'question': u'2 and 6'}]
```

How would I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use builtin function names as variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eval is what you're looking for.

```
a=eval("1")
b=eval("[1,2,3]")
```

will give 1(int) as a, and [1,2,3] (list) as b.
This should also work with your code.